# Github Pages cannot change source to docs folder

Tags: angular, github, github-pages

I'm following the tutorial on this link for "Deploying to GitHub Pages":
https://angular.io/guide/deployment

From what I understand of this command:

```
ng build --prod --output-path docs --base-href /<project_name>/
```

I am using the Angular CLI to build the prod files into a docs folder.

Now in GitHub pages, it seems it is looking just at the ReadMe file, I guess because it doesn't know to look in docs folder. I also can't change the source in the settings:
[image]

I'm not sure how to remedy this, as the published site is just showing the generic page that is pulling from README.md

Answer (score 1):

I learned from this posting that you cannot change the source:
[stackoverflow question answering that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45726198/github-wont-let-me-change-the-source-of-my-personal-website-to-gh-pages-branch)

You basically have to put all your production built files on the root (in this case master branch root), and probably keep another branch that has your development files.

Also I come across this odd issue where you have to pick a theme on GitHub before it attempts to publish your files.